# How does Java implements the methods declared in the Annotations (Metadata)?

Tags: java, annotations

An image taken from a book which I am going through,

[image]

The caption says it all. Please suggest or give me something as to what happens behind the scenes.

For example, how does `@NotNull` in Hibernate `Bean Validation API` works?

I know that through Reflection API, we can do something like this,

```
class Meta {

    // Annotate a method.
    @MyAnno(str = "Annotation Example", val = 100)
    public static void myMeth() {

        Meta ob = new Meta();
        // Obtain the annotation for this method
        // and display the values of the members.
        try {
            // First, get a Class object that represents
            // this class.
            Class c = ob.getClass();
            // Now, get a Method object that represents
            // this method.
            Method m = c.getMethod("myMeth");
            // Next, get the annotation for this class.
            MyAnno anno = m.getAnnotation(MyAnno.class);
            // Finally, display the values.
            System.out.println(anno.str() + " " + anno.val());
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException exc) {
            System.out.println("Method Not Found.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        myMeth();
    }
}
```

Comment: The annotations themselves don't have any implementing code. You can only declare fields and later read them using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Annotations don't have any implemented code and actually don't do anything themself.

To make them "work", there should be some kind of annotation processor (initializer, loader or any class that works with annotated objects). This annotation processor checks annotation objects annotations and changes the way it is handled.

For example Spring annotation processor, when initializing an object, looks for @Autowired fields, to fill autowired fields.

Same goes for Hibernates @NotNull. it doesn't do anything actually. However, Hibernate, when persisting your object, checks if there should be something there.